# Is it possible to track user gestures on the iphone touch screen?

Tags: iphone, xcode

What I mean is to be able to track the users' gestures across all apps or the homescreen of the apple iphone. Meaning that this functionality should be running in the background. Anybody got a clue about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to do so, at least not with the public API.